# PayPal Standard payments returning contribution status Pending

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, paypal

I've tried to search through the questions but not found anything similar (apologies if I have missed it). We have CiviCRM 5.24.4 and Drupal 7.72 with PayPay Standard. Payments are coming back as Pending, and when I check the error logs in CiviCRM, I see this:

> Jul 09 10:51:48  [warning] Civi\Payment\PropertyBag related deprecation warnings:
> We have merged input params into the property bag for now but please rewrite code to not use this.
> Unknown property 'qfKey'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'entryURL'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> We have translated 'first_name' to 'firstName' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
> We have translated 'last_name' to 'lastName' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
> Unknown property 'postal_code-1'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'country-1'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'gender_id'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_182'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_180'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_188'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_198'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_190'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'custom_181'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'hidden_processor'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'email-5'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'payment_processor_id'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'priceSetId'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'price_41'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'MAX_FILE_SIZE'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'ip_address'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'amount'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> We have translated 'currencyID' to 'currency' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
> Unknown property 'is_pay_later'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'is_quick_config'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'skipLineItem'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'line_item'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'contributionTypeID'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'financialTypeID'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'financial_type_id'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'contributionType_name'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'financialType_name'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'contributionType_accounting_code'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'financialType_accounting_code'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'contributionPageID'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'payment_instrument_id'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
> Unknown property 'item_name'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
>
> Array
> (
> [civi.tag] => deprecated
> )
>
> Jul 09 10:52:20  [info] $IDS Detector Details = Array
> (
> [0] => Array
> (
> [name] => custom
> [value] => >{"module":"contribute","contactID":"2","contributionID":582,"contributionPageID":1}
> [page] => /civicrm/payment/ipn/2
> [userid] =>
> [session] => 7e6cCxYqli9vVTipHyrcpCW2ybcsyXYifqMzZMwH0HU
> [ip] => 173.0.82.126
> [reaction] => 0
> [impact] => 32
> )
>
> )
>
> Jul 09 10:52:20  [debug] PayPalIPN: Received (ContactID: 2; trxn_id: 7K136571S8727801B).
>
> Jul 09 10:52:20  [debug] Returning since contribution status is Pending

Not sure what to do with this so any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you sort this out? I just ran into the same issue and am seeing the same backtrace.